# dc.js - x-axis not changing on date range change

Tags: dc.js

I have a timeChart that I'm trying to redraw the x-axis when I change the date range selected.

I have set with elasticX set to true,the date is being filtered fine but the x-axis doesn't update with the new range? Here is what I have within my last 7 days button

```
    ndweek = new Date(maxDate);
    ndweek.setDate(ndweek.getDate() - 7);
    timeChart.x(d3.time.scale().domain([ndweek,maxDate]));
    timeDimension.filterRange([ndweek,maxDate]);
    dc.redrawAll();
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the latest 2.0 alpha2 from master? I put in some fixes to elasticX in July.

Comment: Hi Gordon. I've just swapped back to using 2.0.0-dev instead of 2.0 alpha2 and it's now working again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh. Well that's bad news for me; I must have broken something. Thanks for the report!

Comment: I finally [created an issue for this](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/791), but I realized I don't have nearly enough info to reproduce this.  If this still affects you, could you comment there?  Preferably with a jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi Gordon, sorry I've not got back to you sooner. Will see and post if it is still an issue.

Comment: Misunderstood this the first time around. Fixed in 2.0.0-beta.12

Comment: Had this same issue.  After updating dc.js to 2.0.1, the issue was resolved.